# jquery slide not fluid using animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slideshow

I need to do a simple jquery slide. I put some images in a div and i use the animate function to change margin value on it. It works good but the problem is that the slide is not fluid on change images. The image that has to be hide disappear withou sliding (it does as if i use .hide() method). Here is the code i write:

```
$('#slider-container').animate({ marginLeft: "-" + margin_slider + "px"}, 500 );
```

while the html code is:

```
<div id="slider">
    <div id="slider-container">
        <img src="image1" />
        <img src="image2" />
        <img src="image3" />
        <img src="image4" />
    </div>
</div>
```

div slider has a fixed width (equals to image width) and has overflow: hidden.
How can i do?
Thanks, Mattia

Comment: You might get more help if you post additional info (like the css).  A jsfiddle link would be a great way to get some advice.

Answer (score 0):

I did set a width to slider-container, so it took the slider width and the images didn't float left, but one under the other making the slideshow not fluid